# iterate over a list of lists with another list in python

Tags: python, list

I am wondering if I can iterate over a list of lists with another list in python:

let's say

```
lst_a = [x,y,z]  
lst_b = [[a,b,c,d],[e,f,g,h],[i,j,k,l]]
```

where len(lst_a) = len(lst_b)

I am wondering how to get a new list like below:

```
lst_c = [[x/a, x/b, x/c, x/d],[y/e, y/f, y/g, y/h],[z/i, z/j, z/k, z/l]]
```

thanks a lot!

tim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension

```
>>> lst_a = [1,2,3]
>>> lst_b = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]]
>>> lst_c = [[i/b for b in j] for i,j in zip(lst_a, lst_b)]
>>> lst_c
[[1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333, 0.25], [1.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.5, 0.4], [1.0, 0.75, 0.6, 0.5]]
```

Comment: would you happen to know where i might look for more info so as to learn nested list comprehension better?

Comment: [This page](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) seems to be pretty thorough. Don't worry about the nesting just yet, just read the page to understand the list comprehension, then you'll see the nesting is just one step past that.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst_a = [x,y,z]  
lst_b = [[a,b,c,d],[e,f,g,h],[i,j,k,l]] 
lst_c = []

for i in range(len(lst_a)):
    lst_c.append([lst_a[i]/lst_b[i][0]])
    for j in range(1, len(lst_b[i])):
        lst_c[i].append(lst_a[i]/lst_b[i][j])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using numpy.

```
import numpy

lst_a = [x,y,z]  
lst_b = [[a,b,c,d],[e,f,g,h],[i,j,k,l]] 
new_list = []

for i, item in enumerate(lst_a):
   new_list_i = float(lst_a[i])/numpy.array(lst_b[i])
   new_list.append(new_list_i.tolist())

print new_list
```